# Выборка из таблицы записей с максимальным значением с интервалом в 5 минут

Tags: mysql, group-by

Есть таблица `results`:

```
id|user_id|result|result_date
 1|      1|     5|2019-05-20 00:01:10
 2|      1|    10|2019-05-20 00:03:10
 3|      2|     2|2019-05-20 01:01:10
 4|      2|     7|2019-05-20 01:04:10
 5|      3|     6|2019-05-20 02:06:10
 6|      3|     1|2019-05-20 02:07:10
 7|      4|     9|2019-05-20 03:08:10
 8|      4|     5|2019-05-20 03:06:10
```

Нужно выбрать для каждого пользователя запись с максимальным `result` с группировкой по 5 минут, Пробовал сделать так:

```
SELECT user_id,
       id,
       MAX(result),
       result_date - INTERVAL (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`result_date`) % 300) SECOND
FROM results
WHERE result_date BETWEEN '2019-05-20 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-20 23:59:59'
GROUP BY result_date - INTERVAL (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`result_date`) % 300) SECOND
```

Выбирает всё правильно, кроме `id`

P.s. версия MySQL 5.6

Comment: 1) А оно реально надо, это `id`? 2) Версию MySQL укажите.

Comment: 1)обязательно 2)MySQL 5.6

Comment: Тогда только подзапрос для получения макс. значения и в основном запросе выбирать по нему... и неясно, что делать, если в диапазоне будет два равных максимума... PS. Информацию о версии - добавьте в текст вопроса.

Comment: Если два равных максимума, то можно взять тот, у кого id меньше

Comment: "Можно" - неинтересно. Должно быть "нужно". Но если так - то это уже будут два вложенных подзапроса. Сперва макс. значение, потом по нему мин. id, и в основном запросе собственно запись.

Comment: Хорошо, нужно) А можно текст запроса с подзапросом? Не совсем понятно, как должен подзапрос выглядеть

Comment: Внутренний подзапрос уже написан (только id там лишний). Его связываете со второй копией таблицы по равенству выбранных полей и берёте MIN(id). Его связываете с третьей копией таблицы и выбираете запись.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93846/discussion-between-alexey-presman-and-akina).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью @Akina пришёл к следующему решению:

```
     SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT results.id,
                results.user_id,
                results.result,
                results.result_date -
                INTERVAL (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(results.result_date) % 300) SECOND AS result_time
         FROM results
                  JOIN (
             SELECT user_id,
                    MAX(result)                                                         AS result,
                    result_date - INTERVAL (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`result_date`) % 300) SECOND AS result_date
             FROM results
             WHERE result_date BETWEEN '2019-05-20 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-20 23:59:59'
             GROUP BY result_date, user_id) max_results
                       ON results.user_id = max_results.user_id
                           AND results.result = max_results.result
         ORDER BY user_id, results.result DESC
     ) tmp
WHERE result_time BETWEEN '2019-05-20 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-20 23:59:59'
GROUP BY result_time,
user_id
ORDER BY result_time ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT results.*
FROM results, 
( SELECT MIN(results.id) id
  FROM results, 
  ( SELECT user_id,
           MAX(result) result,
           result_date - INTERVAL (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(result_date) % 300) SECOND result_date
    FROM results
    WHERE result_date BETWEEN '2019-05-20 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-20 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY result_date - INTERVAL (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(result_date) % 300) SECOND
  ) as subq1
  WHERE results.user_id = subq1.user_id
    AND results.result = subq1.result
    AND subq1.result_date = results.result_date - INTERVAL (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(results.result_date) % 300) SECOND
  GROUP BY results.user_id, 
           results.result, 
           results.result_date - INTERVAL (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(results.result_date) % 300) SECOND 
) subq2
WHERE results.id = subq2.id;
```

Выбирается запись с максимальным значением в группе.

Если в группе несколько записей с максимальным значением, выбирается запись с минимальным id.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/483381/12)

PS. Вроде группировка по `results.result` в `subq2` - лишняя... но думать-проверять лень.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вот так:

1. Определяем 5-минутную группу делением на 5 (плюс ведущий ноль слева):

   `-- 20.05.2019 03:08:10 -> 2019052003-01
   concat(
     date_format(result_date, "%Y%m%d%H"),
     "-",
     LPAD(floor(date_format(result_date, "%i") / 5), 2, "0")
   ) AS d`
2. Объединяем таблицу саму с собой по идешке пользователя и 5-минутной группе (убрал лишнее из цитаты):

   `left join (<тот же запрос на данные>) on user_id.. and d..`
3. А теперь одновременно просим из второй таблицы записи только бОльшие чем в первой:

   `and <вторая>.result > <первая>.result`

   но при этом исключаем такие случаи из результата

   `where <вторая>.id is null`

И как следствие в выборку попадут только записи у которых для одного юзера и группы НЕТ и не может быть записей в этой же таблице с бОльшим значением `result`.

Итоговый запрос (он страшный т.к. мне нужны ваши тестовые данные внутри подзапросов, у вас будет короче и понятнее):

```
select t12.*
from (
    select *, concat(date_format(result_date, "%Y%m%d%H"), "-", LPAD(floor(date_format(result_date, "%i") / 5), 2, "0")) d
    from (
        select 1 as id, 1 as user_id, 5 as result, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 00:01:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as result_date union all
        select 2, 1, 10, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 00:03:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 3, 2, 2, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 01:01:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 4, 2, 7, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 01:04:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 5, 3, 6, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 02:06:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 6, 3, 1, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 02:07:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 7, 4, 9, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 03:08:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 8, 4, 5, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 03:16:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
    ) t11
) t12
left join (
select *
from (
    select *, concat(date_format(result_date, "%Y%m%d%H"), "-", LPAD(floor(date_format(result_date, "%i") / 5), 2, "0")) d
    from (
        select 1 as id, 1 as user_id, 5 as result, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 00:01:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as result_date union all
        select 2, 1, 10, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 00:03:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 3, 2, 2, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 01:01:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 4, 2, 7, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 01:04:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 5, 3, 6, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 02:06:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 6, 3, 1, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 02:07:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 7, 4, 9, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 03:08:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') union all
        select 8, 4, 5, STR_TO_DATE("2019-05-20 03:16:10", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
    ) t21
) t22
) t23 on t12.user_id = t23.user_id and t12.d = t23.d and t23.result > t12.result
where t23.id is null
```

В последней записи поменял время чтоб для юзера 4 не было второй записи с такой же группой. Для проверки левого джоина.